# Popover not dismissing after row is selected

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am creating a monotouch ipad app. I have a popover with tableview in it. When i select a row i want the popover to dismiss/close.

Now what happens is when i select a row the popover remains on the screen and i have to click outside the popover to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin [CoreAnimation](http://new-docs.xamarin.com/Samples/Details?type=MonoTouch&id=96) (source on [github](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/CoreAnimation)) sample uses a popover (with a table within) when used in **portrait** mode (it's not shown on the screenshots).

You should be able to reuse the same code inside your own application.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a delegate of the popover viewcontroller class and then on clicking on tableview call that delegate method to remove the popover view.
if you want to learn more see this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)